# securely authenticating users as a third-party

Tags: security, authentication

Let's say i'm writing a program or app that requires me to authenticate users on their behalf, i.e. ask a user for their credentials to log in to a website or something to retrieve and process data.

How can i do something like this in such a way that the user's security is guaranteed, preferably so that i can't even see the credentials they've provided at all. And if this is not possible, how can users be assured that their privacy and security is not compromised in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer, but probably not useful to you is:

You can't guarantee privacy and security are not compromised! And as the admin on the server, if you receive and store user credentials, you could access them.

[Immutable Law #6 of Security: A computer is only as secure as the administrator is trustworthy](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/988/485)

So think about what level of security you would accept as appropriate.

You could use something like OpenID, like StackExchange uses - it removes the authentication piece from their responsibility. Only the OpenID provider receives credentials - SE just gets a token from them.